# Detecting ImportError in imported module

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace

I want to import a Python module if it exists, but ignore the `ImportError` if it does not. However, if the imported module itself raises an `ImportError`, this error will be ignored too, and that's not what I need (i.e. if the module **exists**, but **has some bug**, I want to know).

```
for app in INSTALLED_APPS:
    try:
        module = __import__('{}.mycustommodule'.format(app))
        # Do something with it
    except ImportError:
        traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]
        if ( ? ):  # if the exception occurred in app.mycustommodel, raise
            raise
        pass       # otherwise, ignore
```

I checked the docs for [sys.exc_info](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) and [traceback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) but didn't find any useful info. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the exception occurred in the same function that is catching it, the stack trace will have only one frame. Otherwise, it will have multiple frames. After looking at [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10115022/520779) and making some tests, I found out it's enough to check if `tb_next` is `None`:

```
except ImportError:
    traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]
    if ( traceback.tb_next ):
        raise
    pass
```

**Note:** Although documentation on `tb_next` is scarce (saw a reference to it in the docs for [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/inspect.html), but nothing specifying what constitutes a traceback "level"), the behavior above is consistent between [Python 2.7.3](http://ideone.com/E7zABo), [Python 3.2.3](http://ideone.com/0lEdfR), Jython 2.5.3, IronPython 2.7.3 and PyPy 1.8.0.

Comment: Sounds like it could be implementation and/or release dependent if it's not documented.

Comment: @martineau Good point, I'll watch out for this! I may test it in a few different environments (CPython, PyPy) and see if there are any differences.