# Refactor error handling and get the right stacktrace in Python

Tags: python, debugging, refactoring, stack-trace

I got a lot of code like this :

```
try:
   # do a lot of stuff
except StuffError as e:
    log.exception(e):
    send_mail_to_admin()
    raise e
```

For DRY, I wanted to refactor that into :

```
def post_mortem(log, e):
    log.exception(e):
    send_mail_to_admin() 
    # some other stuff
    raise e
```

Then do :

```
try:
   # do a lot of stuff
except StuffError as e:
    post_mortem(log, e)
```

The trouble is now I don't get the proper stack trace, since the exception is raised from another file.

How can I get the same stack trace I would have had with the first code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..you wanted it DRY? Try this then :)

```
class ReportExceptions(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        if exc_type is not None:
            print("Sending mail to admin about {0!r}".format(exc_value))
```

And use it like this:

```
with ReportExceptions():
    # your code here..
```

With a context manager, you don't have to care about re-raising exceptions, saving tracebacks or other things: the `__exit__()` method will be executed no matter what, passing you the necessary information. If you do nothing about it (eg. `return True`) the exception will just continue its way out..

**Side note:** you can instantiate the context manager only once, for example:

```
class ReportExceptions(object):
    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        if exc_type is not None:
            print("Sending mail to {0!r} about {1!r}"
                  "".format(self.email, exc_value))

report_exceptions = ReportExceptions('foo@bar.com')
```

then:

```
with report_exceptions:
    # ..your code here..
```

### FYI: raising an exception with custom traceback

In case you really need to re-raise an exception, you can save the traceback and keep it for later..

```
try:
    100 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError, e:
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()
```

...later on...

```
raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
```

(The syntax is actually `raise expression, expression, expression`, I couln't figure out a nicer way to use the tuple directly...)

### Inspecting frames along the path

You can access `tb` attributes to inspect the execution frames along the path, for example the locals from the "most external" point would be `tb.tb_frame.f_locals`, the inner frame is at `tb.tb_next.tb_frame`, etc...

(you can also use the `inspect` module, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115462/148845)

Comment: Ah, this is beautiful. Actually, I'm going to make a decorator out of it.

Comment: Whooops, actually I do need to catch the exception, because I need to log the traceback as well.

Comment: A mix between the two solution is probably the way to go. I'm going to make some tests, but if somebody has an idea, I'll take it any day.

Comment: @e-satis the third argument to ``__exit__`` (``tb``) **is** the traceback you're looking for :)

Comment: Great ! Can you access the block locals() as well ?

Comment: @e-satis: you should be able to pass them as argument to context manager constructor, but it doesn't sound like a good idea, accessing locals from the context manager.. why do you need that?

Comment: (if that's for debugging purposes, I'm pretty sure you can do some trickery, by inspecting frames in the traceback or similar.. I'd have to check how frameworks like django/werkzeug do that)

Comment: Ok, I double-checked and updated my answer :) Just make sure you don't get tempted to do things like, for example, altering locals or other magic that might end up badly ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `exc_info()` information also, as one of the parameters like this

```
post_mortem(log, e, sys.exc_info()[2])
```

And in the `post_mortem`

```
def post_mortem(log, e, traceBack):
    traceback.print_tb(traceBack)
```

To get the entire stacktrace, you can do like shown in this example

```
import traceback, sys

def post_mortem(log, e, tb):
    print "".join(traceback.format_list(traceback.extract_stack()[:-2]) + [traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]])

def throwError():
    try:
        raise NameError("I don't like your name")
    except NameError as e:
        post_mortem("", e, sys.exc_info()[2])

def callThrowError():
    throwError()

callThrowError()
```

**Output**

```
  File "/home/thefourtheye/Desktop/Test.py", line 15, in <module>
    callThrowError()
  File "/home/thefourtheye/Desktop/Test.py", line 13, in callThrowError
    throwError()
  File "/home/thefourtheye/Desktop/Test.py", line 8, in throwError
    raise NameError("I don't like your name")
```

Comment: +1 cause it's a bit better, but I don't get the line where the exception occurs, I only get the line where it's caught.

Comment: @e-satis I believe, it gives only the line which raises the exception.

Comment: Explicitly passing traceback object is unnecessary. How about accessing `sys.exc_info()` inside `post_mortem`?

Comment: Context managers is the way :) No catching / no need to re-raise / no risk of harming the exception