# Display source code causing an exception in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, inspection

How to retrieve the line of code (not the line number) that causes an exception?

This is an attempt.

```
import sys, inspect
try:
    1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    code = str(inspect.getsourcelines(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code))        

print(code)
```

It returns the first line of the script, not the line that causes the exception.

```
(['import sys, inspect\n'], 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below codes works, but it is inflexible. Someone else may have better solution.

```
import sys, inspect
try:
    y = 2
    a = 1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    exception_occr_at_file = inspect.trace()[0][1]
    line_no = inspect.trace()[0][2]
    code = inspect.trace()[0][4]

print(exception_occr_at_file)
print(line_no)
print(code)

#Ouput:
C:\Users\jianc\Desktop\test\test_print.py
4
['    a = 1 / 0\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to spinx's answer, there are [attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.FrameInfo) in every `FrameInfo` object

So we can make the code more readable by using them:

```
import sys, inspect

try:
    y = 2
    a = 1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    exception_occr_at_file = inspect.trace()[0].filename
    line_no = inspect.trace()[0].lineno
    code = inspect.trace()[0].code_context

print(exception_occr_at_file)
print(line_no)
print(code)
```

---

I also wasn't too happy with the random indexing at `0` for the frames. Reading the [description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.trace) of `inspect.info`, it doesn't sound like the correct position is being indexed.

> `inspect.trace(context=1)`
> Return a list of `FrameInfo` objects for the stack between the current frame and the frame in which an exception currently being handled was raised in. The first entry in the list represents the caller; the last entry represents where the exception was raised.

`0` will give the line of the caller, not the thrower. A nice example is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115462/8548828). (I'm copying it here for easy of use.)

```
import sys
import inspect
from pprint import pprint


def errorer():
    raise Exception('foo')

def syser():
    try:
        errorer()
    except Exception, e:
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        print tb.tb_frame
        print tb.tb_lasti
        print tb.tb_lineno
        print tb.tb_next

def inspecter():
    try:
        errorer()
    except Exception, e:
        pprint(inspect.trace())
```

With the following output:

```
>>> syser()
<frame object at 0x1441240>
6
10
<traceback object at 0x13eb3b0>
>>> inspecter()
[(<frame object at 0x14a5590>,
  '/tmp/errors.py',
  22,
  'inspecter',
  None,
  None),
 (<frame object at 0x14a21b0>,
  '/tmp/errors.py',
  8,
  'errorer',
  None,
  None)]
```

We can clearly see that indexing at `0` gives us the line the function `errorer` is called in `inspecter` and `-1` gives us the point where we throw the exception.

So if we want to know which line throws the exception, `-1` is correct, if we however want to know the root of our call tree of a failing function/object, `0` is correct.